# how to in including ViewPagerIndicator

Tags: android, viewpagerindicator

i am trying to include ViewPagerIndicator in my project. if i a create a new project its possible to include this library but i cant include it in my imported project. here is screenshot of my problem in eclipse.
[problem picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oGmOg.png)

and here is my manifest file

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.swipetabs"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".FragmentA"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_fragment" >
    </activity>
</application>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your project and your library is in different path. Make sure that both are in same folder and try it once more . it will work